# select top 10 in total sum in mysql table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have MySQL table as bellow

```
id, name, postcode, address
```

in my, table postcode will be like this

```
AX12 3NB
NB76 5BQ
AX23 6NB
AX87 6CZ
```

I want to get top 10 Postcode in total like postcode start with AX appear 3 times

I have Laravel project and want to do in this syntax

```
DB::table('users')
```

I want to get the total number of any postcode first 2 letters and only the top 10 records.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit you question to include an example of the output you want?

Comment: I want to get the total number of any postcode (first 2 letters) and only the top 10 records.

Comment: Prepared raw SQL query for you:
`select count(postcode) as occurences, substring(postcode, 1, 2) as top from Temp group by top order by occurences desc limit 10;`

Comment: And what have you tried? You'll need some custom logic to group/count by the first 2 letters of the post code. Remember, Stackoverflow is not a code writing service; you're expected to make an effort, and we'll assist with debugging/QA

Comment: Here it is in Laravel
$users = DB::table('Temp')
                     ->select(DB::raw('<Your RAW SQL Query>'))
                     ->get();

Comment: Hello @Amir Saleem, yes I did same before but I dont know how to use it in Laravel, I don't want to use RAW SQL Query

Comment: Hey, I have never touched Laravel in my life, this is what I created from the given documentation 
`$users = DB::table('users')->select('count(postcode) as occurences', 'substring(postcode, 1, 2) as top')->groupBy('top')->orderBy('occurences', 'desc')->offset(0)->limit(10)->get();`  
you can try this

Comment: I am getting this error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count("postcode")'

Answer (score 1):

First, get all the records, then use PHP to sort and reduce the size of the array. The best way to do this is with a raw query, but since you stated above that you don't want to use a raw query, this is a quick way to handle it.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$postcodes_array = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $first_two = substr($user->postcode, 0, 2);
    if (isset($postcodes_array[$first_two])) {
        $postcodes_array[$first_two] += 1;
    } else {
        $postcodes_array[$first_two] = 1;
    }
}
arsort($postcodes_array);
$postcodes_array = array_slice($postcodes_array, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Thx , did you suggest any clean raw query ?

Comment: I have this query but its giving me an error 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to


$data=DB::table('users')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(`postcode`) as occurences'))
        ->where(DB::raw('substring(postcode, 1, 2) as top'))
        ->groupBy('top')
        ->orderBy('occurences', 'desc')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();